# How to join or merge provider.patterns array from multiple yml files in serverless.yml and also how to set enabled flag on scheduled events

Tags: amazon-web-services, yaml, serverless-framework

I have serverless_common.yml file for all shared things across all my lambdas and I have serverless.yml in my individual service when I try to import `package.patterns` in to my individual service yml file I get following error when I do `sls print`

```
Serverless Error ----------------------------------------
 
  Configuration error: 
       at 'functions.app.events[0]': unrecognized property 'enabled'
       at 'package.patterns[0]': should be string

Your Environment Information ---------------------------
     Operating System:          darwin
     Node Version:              14.16.1
     Framework Version:         2.46.0 (local)
     Plugin Version:            5.4.0
     SDK Version:               4.2.3
     Components Version:        3.12.0
```

```yaml
#serverless_common.yml
package:
  patterns:
  - '!target/**'
  - '!tests/**'
  - '!test/**'
  - '!tools/**'
  - '!README.md'
  - '!node_modules/.bin/**'
  - '!serverless/**'
  - '!.*'
```

```yaml
#service1/serverless.yml
package:
  individually: true
  patterns: 
    - something-specific-to-service1
    - ${file(../serverless_common.yml):package.patterns}
functions:
  app:
    handler: index.handler
    name: service1
    events:
      - schedule: cron(0 09 * * ? *)
        enabled: false
```

```
serverless_common.yml        
/service1
  |- package.json     
  |- index.js
  |- serverless.yml   
/service2
  |- package.json    
  |- index.js
  |- serverless.yml
```

Answer (score 1):

The errors are warning you that you've got two indentation issues.
The first is in your `serverless_common.yml` file. The array items should be indented one place further:

```
#serverless_common.yml
package:
  patterns:
    - '!target/**'
    - '!tests/**'
    - '!test/**'
    - '!tools/**'
    - '!README.md'
    - '!node_modules/.bin/**'
    - '!serverless/**'
    - '!.*'
```

The second is in your cron expression. The one-line syntax is only if you're not using other arguments. Since you want to pass `enabled: false`, you'll need to use the multiline syntax:

```
#service1/serverless.yml
functions:
  app:
    handler: index.handler
    name: service1
    events:
      - schedule:
          rate: cron(0 09 * * ? *)
          enabled: false
```

Unfortunately, the syntax you've chosen won't merge the two arrays. You'll have to reference each item in your array individually, or rewrite your `serverless.yml` into a `serverless.js` file, which allows you to be more programmatic.

```
package:
  individually: true
  patterns: 
    - something-specific-to-service1
    - ${file(../serverless_common.yml):package.patterns.foo}
    - ${file(../serverless_common.yml):package.patterns.bar}
    # ... etc
```

Comment: Thank you. 
Second one seems to be working fine after I added indentation. Where as I get same error with first `Configuration error at 'package.patterns[1]': should be string`

Comment: I've edited my answer. Unfortunately, if you've got a ton of exclusions, you should consider either refactoring them to be in some predictable format (that a glob can match, IE `foo.tests.js` and then exclude `*.test.js`), or use `serverless.js` and merge in code.